# How to close modal when the subscriber receive data in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap modals, I want to use it also as loading modal when I call async REST services.
So I open it before calling the service and I want to close it when the response is received.

**Example**:

```
this.loadingModalRef = this.modalService.show(LoadingModalComponent,{initialState, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' });
this.myService.searchClient(data).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.loadingModalRef.hide()
  }
);
```

In that case the modal dont't close, but I don't understand why.
I have to use a delay to close it, in this way

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.loadingModalRef.hide();
 }, 200);
```

But I have a problem when I want to also navigate to another location when the response is received. In that case the modal is not being closed, is not visible but it is still attached to the body element in the DOM and the user can't interact with the interface anymore.

Is it correct to use a timeout to close the modal?
How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: What modal ????

Comment: It is not a good way to use timeout, because you cant know exactly the time of the process, did you tried To de bug? Make à breakpoint in the observer  registered on searchClient, may be there is an error of calling searchClient, add error check on your observer

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm trying to close a ngx-bootstrap modal inside the subscribe method of an observable

Answer (score 1):

<s>When using setTimeout `this` context is equal to `window` so you should use `bind`</s>

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.loadingModalRef.hide();
}, 200).bind(this)
```

And in first code this should work:

```
const loadingModalRef = this.modalService;
loadingModalRef.show(LoadingModalComponent,{initialState, keyboard: false, backdrop: 'static' });
this.myService.searchClient(data).subscribe(
  res => {
    loadingModalRef.hide()
  }
);
```

Comment: with arrow functions 'this' context is not equal to 'window'

Comment: @Marco24690 you are right, i'm sorry for misleading you i will correct my answer

Comment: the code you write should work as I expected, but unfortunately it doesn't. If I try to close the modal without the timeout it doesn't hide.

Comment: @Marco24690 corrected again. I didnt realize `service.show()` doesn't return reference the service (why would it). We are only saving `this.service` to `modalRef` right now and that should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to set `this` into that.

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(() => {
   that.loadingModalRef.hide();
}, 200);
```

In my case , It works for me.

The other way to do that is.

```
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
) { }
```

And then make a function to close modal. And call that function.

```
closeModal() {
 this.activeModal.close('');
}
```

See this link for more information. [Link](https://itnext.io/creating-forms-inside-modals-with-ng-bootstrap-221e4f1f5648)

Comment: Thank you for your support, but this doesn't fix the problem for me

Comment: Anyway I don't understand why I have to insert a timeout, can you explane me? @Sachin

Comment: @Marco24690 It is not required to use timeout to close your model. I have just give example based on your question. As you can see , I gave you two way to close your model. And In my case both works well. So , If you don't want to use timeout then please go with my second option. It will close your model with out use timeout.

Comment: I am not using ng-boostrap, but ngx-bootstrap